# How to enforce presence of searchParams on react-router-v6 route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parameters, react-router, react-router-dom

###### The what?

I am making build a React+Typescript app that makes calls to https://swapi.dev to render pages of various resources like `people`, `films` or `planets`.

###### The why?

I need to make sure that the user is not able to manipulate the URL such that they are able to go to `/characters` without specifying a `pageNumber` param like so: `localhost:3000/character?page=1`

###### The how?

As an example I have a route like the one below, where I need to Redirect the user to `/characters?page=1` if they enter enter `/characters`

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="characters"
          element={<SwapiResourcePage resourceType={"people"}
        />
        <Route
          path="characters/:id"
          element={<SwapiResourceDetailsPage resourceType={"people"} 
        />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

###### What have you tried?

I've tried replacing the path to `path=characters?page=:id` and setting it to exact, but this is not valid syntax in `react-router`. Also had a quick glance at https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/ , but I couldn't find anything relevant.

###### How can I help ?

I need help figuring out how to enforce searchParams on a react-router route.

Comment: You can get the value of `id` using the `useParam()` method in the `<SwapiResourcePage />` component, and if the value is undefined then `navigate` to `?page=1` route.

Comment: @SatyaS I tried it , but it does not work. I get the following error: `Warning: Cannot update a component ('BrowserRouter') while rendering a different component ('SwapiResourcePage'). To locate the bad setState() call inside 'SwapiResourcePage', follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this at the route level since queryString parameters are not part of the path. Only the path is used by `react-router-dom` `Route` components.

Use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook in the matched/routed component and check for the `page` queryString parameter and issue an imperative back navigation if it is missing.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SwapiResourcePage = ({ resourceType }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const page = searchParams.get("page");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!page) navigate(-1); // <-- no page param, navigate back
  }, [navigate, page]);

  ...

  if (!page) {
    return null;
  }

  // render content
  ...
```

### Update

It seems like your question was more about providing a fallback `page` queryString value than preventing access to routed content if `page` value was missing. You can use the same code/logic as above, but instead of using `navigate` to issue a back navigation off the route, just update the queryString.

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SwapiResourcePage = ({ resourceType }) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchparams] = useSearchParams();
  const page = searchParams.get("page");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!page) {
      // No page param, replace current
      searchParams.set("page", 1);
      setSearchparams(searchParams, { replace });
    }
  }, [searchParams, setSearchparams, page]);

  ...

  if (!page) {
    return null;
  }

  // render content
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, @SatyaS previously made the same suggestion and I tried this however I get the following error :  `Warning: Cannot update a component ('BrowserRouter') while rendering a different component ('SwapiResourcePage'). To locate the bad setState() call inside 'SwapiResourcePage', follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render`. I ended up creating an intermediary component that validates the searchParams.

Comment: @VyacheslavGorbov No, we did not suggest the same thing. They suggested using the `useParams` hook which won't work since the path for `SwapiResourcePage` hasn't any params. I suggested using the `useSearchParams` hook that reads the queryString params. I suppose I interpreted your question to be something along the lines of "don't allow access to routed content if `page` queryString param is missing", which is a little different than your solution which seems to provide a backup value if the `page` queryString param is missing. I'll update my answer to match this other use case.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up solving this by creating an intermediary component called `<ValidateQueryParams/>`, here's the code I used for those who are interested:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
import validatePageNumber from "../helpers/validatePageNumber";
import SwapiResourcePage from "../pages/SwapiResourcePage";

interface ValidateQueryParamProps {
  resourceType: string;
}

const ValidateQueryParam: React.FC<ValidateQueryParamProps> = ({
  resourceType,
}) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const pageNumber = searchParams.get("page");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      pageNumber == null ||
      !pageNumber.match(/\d+/) ||
      !validatePageNumber(resourceType, parseInt(pageNumber))
    ) {
      setSearchParams({ page: "1" });
    }
  }, []);
  return <SwapiResourcePage resourceType={resourceType} />;
};

export default ValidateQueryParam;
```

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="people"
          element={<ValidateQueryParam resourceType={"people"} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="people/:id"
          element={<SwapiResourceDetailsPage resourceType={"people"} />}
        />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```